# Overloading of %in% operator in R

Tags: r, operator-overloading, overloading

I've problems in overloading the %in% operator in R. After overloading the == operator too because my "Type" class is not a basic value in R and %in%:

```
setMethod("==", signature(e1 = "Type", e2 = "ANY"), function (e1, e2) {
    class(e2)=="Type" && e1$name == e2$name
})  
setMethod("==", signature(e1 = "ANY", e2 = "Type"), function (e1, e2) {
    class(e1)=="Type" && e1$name == e2$name
})  

setMethod("%in%", signature(e1 = "Type", e2 = "list"), function (e1, e2) {
    for (i in e2) {
        if (e1 == i)
            return(TRUE);
    }
    return(FALSE);
})
```

The last method returns the following error

```
Creating a generic function from function ‘%in%’ in the global environment
Errore in match.call(definition, call, expand.dots) : 
    unused arguments (e1 = c("Type", ""), e2 = c("list", ""))
```

How could I solve my problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong arguments.  Look at:

```
`%in%`
function (x, table) 
match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
<bytecode: 0x7ffd5984e978>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

You need to change your method to have `x` and `table` as the arguments.  That's why you get the error `unused arguments (e1 = c("Type", ""), e2 = c("list", ""))`, because `e1` and `e2` aren't part of the generic definition.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the easiest way to overload operators is to do a function similar to the following:

```
"%in%" = function(x,y) {
    if(parameter_condition) {
        response_function
    } else {
    .Primitive("%in%")(x,y)
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way, won't I remove all the previous overridings of the %in% operator (e.g., if a library already overrides it?)

Comment: You will.  If that's a potential issue, I'd go with the above answer. I just wanted to provide another way of performing the task depending on the needs of anyone who comes across this question.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I only wanted to know if this could be used in any possible cotnext... thanks anyway!